# {"Invalid object name 'ICCSS.mdf.TblCustomers'."}

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am getting this error when i run the program i had tried directly running the program from sql server it works but when i use mdf. it gives me that error

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable("VehicleSummary");
            string query = "select Country,State as 'location' from ICCSS.mdf.TblCustomers group by Country";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDb;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\\ICCSS.mdf;";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            var dataView = new DataView(dt);
            new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
            .AddTitle("Chart for Growth [Column Chart]")
            //.AddSeries("Default", chartType: "column", xValue: xValue, yValues: yValue)
            //.AddSeries("Default", chartType: "Bar", xValue: xValue, yValues: yValue)
            //ChartType: "Bar","Column","","","",""
            .AddSeries("Default", chartType: "Column", xValue: dataView, xField: "Country", yValues: dataView, yFields: "location")
            .AddLegend("Summary")
            .Write("bmp");
            return null;
```

Comment: i am getting this error when i run the program i had tried directly running the program from sql server it works but when i use mdf. it gives me that error

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the fully qualified name this way, just use `TblCustomers` directly:

```
string query = "select Country,State as 'location' from TblCustomers group by Country";
```

Then, you will get another error, column `State` cannot be used without an aggregate function, or it should be included in the group by. May be you just need to use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`.